# Aggregate in R taking way too long

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm trying to count the unique values of x across groups y.

This is the function:

```
aggregate(x~y,z[which(z$grp==0),],function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

This is taking way too long (~6 hours and not done yet). I don't want to stop processing as I have to finish this tonight.

`by()` was taking too long as well

Any ideas what is going wrong and how I can reduce the processing time ~ 1 hour?
My dataset has 3 million rows and 16 columns.

Input dataframe z

```
x y grp 
1 1 0
2 1 0
1 2 1
1 3 0 
3 4 1
```

I want to get the count of unique (x) for each y where grp = 0

UPDATE: Using @eddi's excellent answer. I have

```
                  x                 y
     1:           2                 1
     2:           1                 3
```

Any idea how I can quickly summarize this as the number of x's for each value y?
So for this it will be

```
Number of x    y
5              1
1              3
```

Comment: Post a minimal reproducible example, and someone will give you an answer that'll run in well under a minute.

Comment: provide input and expected output. So that it gives some understanding what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The formula method of `aggregate()`  is known to be slower on data frames.  But I'd bet you could stop now and use the *data.table* package instead and still be done on time.  But yes, reproducible example.

Comment: by reproducible example, do you mean that I should give a sample of my dataframe?

Comment: What you gave is fine, we can copy/paste it.  But most users generally prefer the result from `dput()` on some *small* sample of your data (like `dput(head(z))`).

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely do that the next time. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: Why is Number of x 5 when y is 1? Is that a misprint for 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(z) # to convert to data.table in place

z[grp == 0, uniqueN(x), by = y]
#   y V1
#1: 1  2
#2: 3  1
```

Comment: Thanks!
I'm getting an error that says z.grp is a factor that is being joined to a double i.v1.  When i check typeof(z$grp) it still says integer(0) though.

I converted grp to integer using as.numeric(as.character(z$grp)) and am running the code now!

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting that error, factor or not. Either way, use `as.integer(as.character` instead of `as.numeric(as.character` to convert to integer.

Comment: Thanks will do. And for summing instead of unique count, `z[grp == 0, sum(x), by = y]` will do, right? @eddi

Comment: yep, and if you want the non-unique number `z[grp == 0, .N, by = y]`

Comment: Thanks a ton, you saved me a lot of time and unnecessary worry. I've updated my question, any quick solution for that too? Will the table() function work

Comment: @AditSanghvi I'm confused - seems like you've already figured out that you can use `sum(x)` for that..

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
z %>% 
  filter(grp == 0) %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  summarize(nx = n_distinct(x)))
```

is the `dplyr` way, though it may not be as fast as `data.table`.